# UFD that is not a ED?

Tags: ring-theory

Can someone give some examples of a unique factorization domain, that is not a Euclidean domain?

I'm aware of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{-19}]$ and would appreciate any other examples, the simpler the better!

Comment: Would $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be simple enough?

Comment: @JWL Yes it would, but I had thought it was a Euclidean domain with the function v(f(x)) =deg(f(x)). I just realised this is only when the ring is a field, so this is a perfect example!

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{-19}]$?

Comment: There [were six in the DaRT database](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=114&L=113) when this comment was written.